Chrome caching overrides no caching headers in requests
I am trying to disable caching on requests in my app since it contains sensitive data. I am not completely sure if this is possible by just modifying the frontend side of my project but everything that I ran into up until now suggest that it should be
I have modified my interceptors to add the following headers to requests
Interceptor header
I have also tried adding meta tags like these
Meta tags
And I have also tried with modifying the nginx server block of code to add these headers, bot none of these methods work as I can see that the headers are being added to each request yet everything is geting saved in the chrome cache folder.
Am I missing something obvious that could be the solution to this?

caching on client should be irrelevant to security
